# How can I change the owner of a print job in C#

Tags: c#, printing

Is there a way to set the print job owner when printing from a C# program? [I found this for doing it from C++](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1c26b083-9b13-40e0-b675-a82e101e9655/cant-change-print-job-owner-with-setjob?forum=netfxbcl), but as is said in that thread, it doesn't work.